# Fork(), one process doesn't terminate?

Tags: process, fork, wait

I have never get this before; i'm doing a simple program: a father process which creates child processes, and after it terminates; this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



int child(pid_t pid)
{
    printf("process %d is terminating\n",pid);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(fork() == 0)
            child(getpid());
    }
    printf("father, pid=%d terminated\n",getpid());
    /*if(wait(NULL) == -1)
        perror("wait");*/
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

when i run, all processes printed, but one process, i think father but i'm not sure, doesn't terminate because terminal is active(doesn't appear $);
insted, if i insert commented line with wait, program runs correctly; why this?

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJv9n.png)

Comment: Can you post the terminal output that you do see?

Comment: added it;  as you can see, sometimes it runs correctly, sometimes one process dosn't terminate..

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last run in the screen capture, you'll see "process 8429 is terminating" *after* the terminal prompt has been printed to the screen.

What appears to be happening is your "father" process happens to exit first, and your shell then outputs the prompt.  Then, in the last case, the child process (PID 8429) printed its output and then exited.

So it is terminating, but sometimes the child process doesn't terminate until after the parent process exited and your shell process has already printed the prompt.

Just hit "enter" again when it does that, and you should see a proper shell prompt.  Or even enter a command, and it should run normally.